# Mathematical texts: white background or tan

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Why is it that while the vast majority of mathematical textbooks are printed on white paper, a select few are printed on that tan, sand-colored paper that sometimes shows up?

I find the latter very visually appealing, so if it is acceptable in the mathematical community, why don't publishers/authors use this soothing background more, instead of the sharp, distracting, and basically ugly (that's maybe just me?) white?

Would it be acceptable to hand in assignments in this colour (ignoring the costs of printing!), and, since I expect the answer to be no, why not? Is there a 'standard' sand-like colour used in mathematical work, (and if so, what is its precise description since I'd like to use it), or do authors/publishers just pick any one they like?

Sorry if this is a weird question.

Comment: Why do you expect that it would be unacceptable to hand in assignments on a slightly yellowed paper? I doubt any teacher / professor would actually take issue with it ...

Comment: Older profs might prefer the white paper, as it's much easier to read.

Comment: Might be better suited for [academia.stackexchange.com](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You should just ask your professor about his/her preferences.

Comment: I don't really have a problem with white colored background. I would guess, that it's just easier to get a hold of white colored paper since it is "more standard." Not so much math but I feel like at least some of the paper writing formats (MLA, APA, Chicago etc.) require white as the color of choice. There would be less contrast between the black font and tan which may make it hard for people with poor vision to read. Just ask the professor. (This is ALL ENTIRELY speculative and a very unsupported guess, more of something to consider).

Comment: This is not at all specific to mathematics, is it?

Comment: This question ought to be put on hold, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Danu: absolutely. This is a troll.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).